# Remove method (Remove odd numbers)

Tags: python

We want to write a function that removes all the odd numbers in a list.

This is what I finally tried:

```
def eliminate(x):
    for i in range(0, (len(x)-1)):
        if x[i] % 2 != 0:
           x.remove(x[i])
    print(x)
eliminate([1,2,5,6])
```

I get the error: *"List index out of range!"*

I'd really appreciate it if you could help because it's driving me crazy that I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I tried `pop` and `delete` methods too. But I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. It's definitely the 4th line, though. Any ideas?!

Comment: when you remove an element from the list, you shorten the list, so you end up out of range.

Comment: You shouldn't iterate over a list and delete its elements at the same time. If you have 5 cookies and eat the 2nd cookie then the next one is 3 out of 4 that are left. And then you run to 'cookies out of range' because you don't have 5 of them anymore. Solution: create a new list instead, that consists of 4 cookies only. `if x[i] % 2 != 0 new_list.append(x[i])`.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks a lot!
I was trying to stick with one list, but making another list makes it easier!
However, is there probably a way to adapt the iteration length to the list getting shorter?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score -1):

in python, whenever you find yourself doing `for i in range(len(x)):` you *normally* aren't doing things the easiest way.

you could do basically the same thing a few different ways, eg:

```
x = [1,2,5,6]

for i in x:
    if i % 2 == 1:
        x.remove(i)

print x
```

as you can see, you don't need the indexes to do this, the for loop pulls the items out of the list directly.

EDIT - apparently this doesn't work in a general case because python edits the list. seems like `.remove` just isn't a very good way to do this.

another option would be to use a list comprehension:

```
x = [1,2,5,6]

rem = [i for i in x if i % 2 == 0]

print rem
```

or you could use [filter](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#filter) (but i wouldn't because for no particular reason I don't really like filter.)

Comment: Don’t do this, this has the same problem as any other “remove while iterating a list” solution. For an input `x = [1, 3, 2]` this also breaks.

Comment: @poke, huh, I thought it loaded the whole list into memory before iterating. TIL.

Comment: The list is already “in memory” but iterators will operate on the list itself, so by modifying it, you are messing with the iteration state. You would need to create a copy of the list for that to work.